# MAT-FORM-FIELD-OUTLINE label text overlapping with form-field-outline border

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my application, i have 3 step mat-stepper process. In First stepper, i have mat-form-field outline and it works fine but in Second and Third Stepper i have the same mat-form-field outline but the label is overlapping with border line like below.

[image]

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Member ID *</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Test" 
                   formControlName="memberID"                             
                   [(ngModel)]="submitPaymentRequest.getAccount().acctNum">
       <mat-placeholder>TEst</mat-placeholder>
       <mat-error app-validation-message></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

i could see this is happening in IE only not in Chrome.

could any one help on this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please share codes

Comment: I used the same 'mat-form-field appearance="outline"' code in my angular web application projects and i loaded my application via ios in-app browser, the same label is overlapping with border line, it is occurred in iphone 7.
Experts any solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Material Angular does not support IE properly (officialy, IE11+ is supported...).

If IE support is important to your project, use something else like https://materializecss.com/